# Dekker's numerical method interval update confusion

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, numerical-methods

I'm implementing Dekker's numerical method for root finding but I am slightly confused about updating the interval. The wiki on this mentions

> New contrapoint is chosen such that f(a_k+1) and f(b_k+1) have opposite signs. If f(a_k) and f(b_k+1) have opposite signs then the contrapoint remains the same: a_k+1 = a_k. Otherwise, f(b_k+1) and f(b_k) have opposite signs, so the new contrapoint becomes a_k+1 = b_k.

I don't understand what you do in the case that f(a_k) and f(b_k+1) do not have opposite signs. Implementing this part is quite confusing.

Currently I am doing:

```
# check signs of function, if f(bk_k+1) * f(ak) < 0 make no change, else set ak to old bk
if fbk_next * func(ak) < 0:
    ak = ak
else:
    ak = bk
```

It then goes on to mention that:

> If |f(a_k+1)| < |f(b_k+1)|, then a_k+1 is probably a better guess for the solution than b_k+1 and hence the values of a_k+1 and b_k+1 are exchanged.

It's not clear at what point this exchange should happen. Would appreciate any insight and clarification into this portion of Dekker's numerical method algorithm. I have provided my current code so far which seems to converge slightly off.

[Dekker's_method.py](https://pastebin.com/wJ6CMWQT)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about programming, There are many tutorials (and also videos) around

Comment: Dekker's method is hybrid. [Here](https://people.csail.mit.edu/jsolomon/share/book/numerical_book.pdf) at page 173 more details

Answer (score 0):

You have the old bracketing interval `[ a[k], b[k] ]`, possibly in descending order. You get a new point `v[k]` in the interval, the secant root or the midpoint. There is a sign change by the nature of the bracketing interval, so there is still a sign change in one of `[ a[k], v[k] ]` and `[ v[k], b[k] ]`.

In either case, `b[k+1] = v[k]`. In the first case, `a[k+1] = a[k]` and in the second case `a[k+1] = b[k]`.

Especially in the case that `v[k]` is selected as the midpoint/halfway point, but also rarely for the secant root, it can be that the function value at the new point is not the smallest. Then suitable re-arrangements are made to remedy that. The points `a[k+1]` and `b[k+1]` get exchange and the next secant root is computed from them, not from the last two `b` values. This part is, as far as I have seen, not mentioned on wikipedia. Also missing is the minimal step that is required at multiple roots and as last step to reduce the bracketing interval below the error tolerance.